# WWAN and Wi-Fi connection priority on Raspbian Linux

Tags: wireless-networking, dhcp, raspbian

I try set metric in DHCP in Raspbian to had bigger priority Wi-Fi over WWAN so I set:

```
pi@adi:~ $ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ppp0
10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     300    0        0 wwan0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     200    0        0 wlan0
```

But it doesn't work, because when my SIM card (WWAN) don't have any more cash on it, I don't have internet and it doesn't connect via Wi-Fi. What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do failover with metric: Metric just means that among routes with same specifity, the "best" one is always chosen, no matter if something along the connection works or not.

"How do I use different internet connections at the same time" (in diverse variants) is a FAQ, last time was [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1344245/using-bonding-of-ethernet-and-mobile-internet-to-for-high-availability/1344392#1344392).

So you need to somehow determine if you SIM card has cash or not, and based on that script a change of default route.

Comment: But I want only that: allways connect via wifi, where will not be wifi, connect GSM and for that I tried use metric.

Comment: And you can't use a metric for that. That's how it is.

Comment: So how can i? I don't have any idea ;(